# How to uniquely identify elements with selenium for below Expedia site example

Tags: css, selenium, object, xpath, identification

Lets say I go to - https://www.expedia.co.uk/
I go to Trains Tab and do a search for any date with 1 passenger selected.

You'll be on next page where to select trains from a list, now if I want to click on any ***ShowFares*** button its not being recognized uniquely by `CSS= .btn-secondary.btn-action` (its returning more than one matching node. So couldn't use it.

while using xpath -

```
.//*[@id='ember968']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/button
```

I see its recording `@id` with some `emberxxx` which again is not unique as its getting changed for every other search list..

Similarly when I clicked on **ShowFare** then unable to pick a train or fare as same above problem occurring as CSS is returning several nodes and xpath has this emberxxx which is not unique.

Comment: It's matching more than one node because there is more than one node. There are a number of Show Fares buttons depending on your search and how many departures are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with the same attributes, we have more than one element we are not able to pick right one. I tried with jquery selector `.btn-secondary.btn-action:eq(1)` and it is working. By using above selector you will pick first **Show Fares** button every time Let me know if you have any queries.

**CSS Selector:** `.flex-1up.flex-listing.flex-theme-light li:nth-child(1) button`

Comment: Hi Krishna, Thanks for your Answer. I have added its Addon to my Firefox  but not sure how to use Jquery selector.Could you please elaborate more.

Comment: Okay, then its not working for me. Saying Invalid CSS... :(

Comment: Now next thing is to select fare options (after clicking on Show fare button we again might have more than one select buttons for same container), I gave a try but couldn't do it..so just wondering if you can help me on this too..plz

Comment: Sure,sorry for delays actually I'm new to Stack.. wasn't aware of accepting.

Answer (score 1):

Use, for example, xpath-function `starts-with`:

```
(//*[starts-with(@id, 'ember')])[2]
```

This function find part of name. And then you can use filtr by `[]` to find needed element by index.

Comment: No, with this its pointing to header row ..if I keep changing index also its not pointing to Show Fares  button...and as asked in Original question once we click on show fares then also I have same problem in Selecting a fare out of available options..plz see if something can be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see there are lot other elements having same xpath. Here is my suggestion if you want to click on first element.
`//button[@class='btn-secondary btn-action']/span` - push that to list, loop through list and use `getText()`. If matches '**Show Fares**', click on that.

```
List<WebElement> buttonList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn-secondary btn-action']/span"));

for(int i=0; i<=buttonList.size() ; i++){ 
  WebElement ele = buttonList.get(i);
    if(ele.getText().contains("Show Fares"){
        ele.click();
      }

}
```